# Content security policy. webcomponent. script src DataURI .Can I override HTTP HEADER by META tag?

Tags: javascript, firefox, shopify, web-component, content-security-policy

I am is developing a plugin for Shopify CMS. This plugin use webcomponents.js to load Polymer scripts via

```
script.src = "data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(scriptContent);
```

[webcomponentsjs/src/HTMLImports/parser.js line 307](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/0d285e7df994f99341e45bf2b603a1fdb485baae/src/HTMLImports/parser.js#L307)

In FireFox I get the following errors:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,/**script code*/(“script-src https://domainurl https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'”)
```

The original Content security policy header (I can't change this header on the server, because Shopify is a hosted platform and I don't have any control on it)

```
Content-Security-Policy:
default-src 'self' https://*;
child-src 'self' https://* blob: data:; 
connect-src 'self' https://* wss://*;
font-src 'self' https://* blob: data:;
img-src 'self' https://* blob: data:; 
media-src'self' https://* blob: data:;
object-src 'self' https://* blob: data:;
script-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
style-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline';
```

I am trying to overload this header by meta tag

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
    script-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
" />
```

Is it possible to overload header value by meta tag?

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: No, multiple CSPs are always combined towards more restriction. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#enforcing-multiple-policies

Comment: Yes. But I  think I am doing something wrong. Is passable to overload header value? I am not found any information about http header and meta tag behavior on one page.

Comment: It would be useful to see a bit more code for context, specifically the whole block where `script.src = "data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(scriptContent);` exists. Maybe there's a better way to import the code, maybe you just need to put all your script in another .js file and load it in a script tag instead of running the `script.src` stuff directly on the page

Comment: AllTheTime, I have update the post and attached link :  https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/0d285e7df994f99341e45bf2b603a1fdb485baae/src/HTMLImports/parser.js#L307

Comment: You can use HTTPS instead and it should work according to your server CSPs.

Comment: Supersharp, this script tag is generated by js lib, and it is done with DataUri. I have only one solution.Just remove the line with DataUri.

Comment: And use script.textContent to put js string in a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can't manage Content security policy.

I have patched webcomponents.js file.I had removed `script.src = "data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(scriptContent);`.

Now I am loading script by script.textContent.

Comment: _“I found that I can't manage Content security policy”_ – well, if you could, that would make CSP rather useless …

Comment: Ha ha)))I can't manage CSP in both ways, client and server))))